# Own made matrix function prints wrong item position

Tags: python, matrix

I made a function that makes what appears to be a matrix but when printing it out, it doesn't print the correct location for the item in the matrix. The print functions for showing which row and column currently at does print the correct values however, but these values appended does not.

Instead of printing:

```
[00, 01, 02]
[10, 11, 12]
[20, 21, 22]
```

it prints:

```
[20, 21, 22]
[20, 21, 22]
[20, 21, 22]
```

I managed to realize that what it actually prints is:

```
[x0, x1, x2]
[x0, x1, x2]
[x0, x1, x2]
```

where (x = rows - 1) and not the current row which it should.

My script for making the matrix is:

```
rows = 3
cols = 3

matrix = []


def makeMatrix(rows, cols):
    curRow = []

    for row in range(rows):
        curRow.clear()
        print("Row: ", row)

        for col in range(cols):
            print("Col: ", col)
            toAppend = str(row) + str(col)
            curRow.append(toAppend)

        matrix.append(curRow)

    printMatrix()


def printMatrix():
    for item in range(len(matrix)):
        print(matrix[item])


makeMatrix(rows, cols)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you substitute the line `curRow.clear()` line with `curRow = []` you will get your desired output as you can see below:

```
>>> 
('Row: ', 0)
('Col: ', 0)
('Col: ', 1)
('Col: ', 2)
('Row: ', 1)
('Col: ', 0)
('Col: ', 1)
('Col: ', 2)
('Row: ', 2)
('Col: ', 0)
('Col: ', 1)
('Col: ', 2)
['00', '01', '02']
['10', '11', '12']
['20', '21', '22']
```

This was tested under `Python 2.7`.

And actually testing your original code under `Python 3.5` I get the same result:

```
In [21]: makeMatrix(rows, cols)
Row:  0
Col:  0
Col:  1
Col:  2
Row:  1
Col:  0
Col:  1
Col:  2
Row:  2
Col:  0
Col:  1
Col:  2
['00', '01', '02']
['10', '11', '12']
['20', '21', '22']
```

Comment: I used the curRow.clear() because otherwise I got something even worse for an answer. But your suggestion works. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You will override your `curRow` 3 times and then the last value will be the value of that variable. If you do not want this behaviour you will need to clone your list like that:

```
rows = 3
cols = 3

matrix = []


def makeMatrix(rows, cols):
    curRow = []

    for row in range(rows):
        curRow.clear()
        print("Row: ", row)

        for col in range(cols):
            print("Col: ", col)
            toAppend = str(row) + str(col)
            curRow.append(toAppend)

        matrix.append(list.copy(curRow)) #Make a clone

    printMatrix()


def printMatrix():
    for item in range(len(matrix)):
        print(matrix[item])


makeMatrix(rows, cols)
```

Comment: I had no idea of that functionality. Good to know, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are overwriting the rows due to the **nested for**. That's why always take the latest number. You could fix this like this:

```
rows = 3
cols = 3

matrix = []

def make_matrix(rows, cols):
    for row in range(rows):
        curRow = []
        print("Row: ", row)

        for col in range(cols):
            print("Col: ", col)
            toAppend = str(row) + str(col)
            curRow.append(toAppend)

        matrix.append(curRow)

    print_matrix()


def print_matrix():
    for item in range(len(matrix)):
        print(matrix[item])

make_matrix(rows, cols)
```

I hope this helps. Also, I provided better naming for your functions following PEP8 style.